# How to match all keys and values from a custom serialized object format?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, match, capturing-group

I am trying to pick out all values from an object I have in string form. I have created the regular expression, but I am still having issues with not being able to remove the quotes and have hit a wall...

Here is the code I have with results I get compared to desired results:

```
const regex = /(?:"([^"]+)\")|([^=",{}.]+)/g
const string = 'obj{a="0",b="1",domain="a-ss.test.io:666",f="g",range="3.594e-04...4.084e-04"}'

const matches = string.match(regex)
console.log(matches)
```

Here is the resulting array:

```
[
    "obj",
    "a",
    "\"0\"",
    "b",
    "\"1\"",
    "domain",
    "\"a-ss.test.io:666\"",
    "f",
    "\"g\"",
    "range",
    "\"3.594e-04...4.084e-04\""
]
```

Though the desired result I would like is:

```
[
    "obj",
    "a",
    "0",
    "b",
    "1",
    "domain",
    "a-ss.test.io:666",
    "f",
    "g",
    "range",
    "3.594e-04...4.084e-04"
]
```

Does anyone know how to also remove the quotes from each array value that is returned?

Comment: Is this way of serializing an object some recognized format?

Comment: You could probably also use [use `exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) like in [this JS-demo](https://tio.run/##LY9NboMwEIX3nGIyiiJbBYeqFKWJnK56iv4IB4xxBDgCk0aiPjt13G48b8bfm2efxVWM5aAvNrnulqU0/WhhkEregMOWvO6RvH/h5wP9QPrjJcd4dsz3W9UdouiPH@3g6cKczrPgmGJ84viIcWU6oXuOIhlHZuVomTb7PM8xrjkqjAfRK8nxiT2/ZDJJM8ZYxtJd0OgKv76VFnzMd6NbCYR0PiW8jcmbLImPpRRWnEM/tS2FaI4AOlab4U2UjceFLZsY1GCmCwV@hPs9gK5JGB1T2GwgQCs@9ZWsdS8r@k8B3P9mWslao0gRHLCeQ3X3Zes5WF1BD8Hg/Om8dsvyCw).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get whole match values in the result since `String#match` with a regular expression containing the `/g` flag [loses all captures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#return_value). See that `String#match` returns:

> An [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) whose contents depend on the presence or absence of the
> global (`g`) flag, or [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/null) if no matches are found.
>
> - If the `g` flag is used, all results matching the complete regular
>   expression will be returned, but capturing groups are not included.
> - If the `g` flag is not used, only the first complete match and its related capturing groups are returned. In this case, `match()` will return the same result as [`RegExp.prototype.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) (an array with some extra
>   properties).

You want to get Group 1 or Group 2 values, so ask the engine to return just them:

```js
const regex = /"([^"]+)"|([^=",{}.]+)/g
const string = 'obj{a="0",b="1",domain="a-ss.test.io:666",f="g",range="3.594e-04...4.084e-04"}'

const matches = Array.from(string.matchAll(regex), x => x[1] || x[2])
console.log(matches)
```

Answer (score 1):

The next provided approach uses the regex ... [`/(?<key>\p{L}+)="(?<value>[^"]*)"|(?<id>\p{L}+)\{/gu`](https://regex101.com/r/PjNhlx/1) ... which makes use of [named capturing groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups) and [unicode escapes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) (the latter for matching any letter sequence in any language ... `\p{L}+`).

The regex first tries to match and capture `key`-`value` pairs of the form `<key>="<value>"` by its first alternative pattern... `(?<key>\p{L}+)="(?<value>[^"]*)"` ... which matches ...

- and captures any letter sequence of any language ... `(?<key>\p{L}+)`
- followed by the two characters ... `="`
- followed by a captured character sequence that does not contain a double quote ... `(?<value>[^"]*)`
- followed by a double quote ... `"`.

Otherwise it tries to match and capture the object related part of the form `<obj>{ ... }` by its second alternative pattern... `(?<id>\p{L}+)\{` ... which matches ...

- and captures any letter sequence of any language ... `(?<id>\p{L}+)`
- followed by an opening brace ... `\{`.

The pattern then gets consumed by [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) where the return value needs to be transformed into an array in order to be mappable.

The method used is [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) since the callback either returns the captured single `id` value or returns an array of the two other captured values `key` and `value`.

```js
const sampleData = `obj{a="0",b="1",domain="a-ss.test.io:666",f="g",range="3.594e-04...4.084e-04"}`;

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/PjNhlx/1]
const regXTokens = /(?<key>\p{L}+)="(?<value>[^"]*)"|(?<id>\p{L}+)\{/gu;

console.log(
  [...sampleData.matchAll(regXTokens)]
    .flatMap(({ groups: { id, key, value } }) => id || [key, value])
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you don't have characters `{`, `}`, `=`, `"`, `,` in your quoted values you can simply use a `.split()` on those characters:

```js
const string = 'obj{a="0",b="1",domain="a-ss.test.io:666",f="g",range="3.594e-04...4.084e-04"}';
let matches = string.split(/[\{\}\=",]+/).filter(Boolean);
console.log(matches);
```

Output:

```
[
  "obj",
  "a",
  "0",
  "b",
  "1",
  "domain",
  "a-ss.test.io:666",
  "f",
  "g",
  "range",
  "3.594e-04...4.084e-04"
]
```